# Haproxy DNS Based backends based on wildcards

Tags: dns, haproxy, sni

Now that we have a dynamic DNS resolving Backend with Haproxy 1.6, i've been wondering whether I can make resolving to endpoint to dynamic backends. Here's what I would be looking for:

```
resolvers docker
nameserver dnsmasq 127.0.0.1:53

defaults
mode http
log global
option httplog

frontend f_myapp
bind :443
default_backend b_myapp

backend b_myapp
server services *:443 check resolvers docker resolve-prefer ipv4
```

OR

```
server services [%Host]:443 check resolvers docker resolve-prefer ipv4
```

Having this would allow me not to have to touch haproxy's configuration but only use DNS to update the backend-routing.

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: I'm looking for similiar solution, did you happen to achieve this or is this currently achievable in 1.9 version? Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

A `server` declared in HAProxy is a single destination IP address.  Even if that IP address is dynamic and can change, as is now possible in 1.6, a `server` is only/always/ever a single destination, not a target that changes with each request.  What you are contemplating is not consistent with the design of HAProxy.

Your back-end servers must be declared in advance.  You can create dummies and modify them via the stats socket, and dynamic configuration can be accomplished by scripting the configuration-file-generating process (using external tools) and then reloading HAProxy but... it has no internal concept matching what you are contemplating.

Additionally, of course, even if it did,  is a problem with your plan -- it represents a potential security hole: if HAProxy were to interpret `%[Host]` (which I assume refers to `%[req.hdr(host)]`) as an IP address, no resolution would be needed and you've just given internal access to anyone who passed an IP address in the Host header.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already thought that that is going to be the answer. Other SNI Based Proxies allow restricting the domains so that only some domains will be proxied.